# jquery set timeout error

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, timeout

I have a simple jQuery AJAX funciton:

```
$.ajax({ 
 type: "GET",
 url: "json/" + address,
 dataType: "json",
 timeout: 1000,  
 data: "username=" + username + "&paging_limit=" + paging_limit,
 success: function(json){alert("somthing")},
 error: function(){alert("somthing else")}
});
```

I get the following error in Firefox (3.6) when the request times out,

```
setting a property that has only a getter
[Break on this error] null}};try{var h=x.abort;x.abort=funct...return!a.status&&location.protocol===
```

The only fix is that of not setting a custom 'timeout' setting.

Has anyone come across this before, should I be concerned, is there a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be cool if you could try it with the non-minified version of jQuery.

Comment: Also what version of jQuery are we talking about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because JQuery is attempting to *set* the `readyState` of the XHR object: `xhr.readyState = 0;` in its error handling code. Essentially it is trying to replace the abort logic of the XHR with its own. It does not look like this is allowed in Firefox 3.6. I'll check the JQuery source repository to see if this is a known bug.

UPDATE: It is: [Bug report](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5923)

This bug was fixed in JQuery 1.4.1.

Comment: Thanks a million, that was destroying my noodle. Just getting plain old warnings again :)